# Website showing up as older version of Internet Explorer in IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, browser-detection

I built a website for a client [that is located here](http://unitedconstruction.com/)

It is using a child theme of twenty-thirteen and WordPress 3.9.1.

The problem is that on the CEO's computer the website is showing incorrectly in Internet Explorer. He is using IE `v.11.0.9600.1704` (update version 11.0.7). The slider is not showing up, the alignment is off, the social media buttons don't display correctly, and the padding in the footer is incorrect (amongst other things). Here is a screenshot:

[image]

In all other browsers, the website looks fine on his computer (Chrome, Firefox, etc.).

I installed the Advanced Browser Check plugin to give a warning to people using older browsers and the warning window *does* appear on his computer in IE 11 even though it is set to only show if someone is using IE 8 or below.

I can not replicate this problem on any other computer so far. I have tested on 4 or 5 computers including others in his office with IE 11 and on various versions of IE on my own computer. The only time anything like this happens is in IE 8 and below in my tests.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? It seems like it is not picking up some of the modern CSS or the slider. Could he be missing a plugin on his Internet Explorer 11 (javascript, etc)? Why would the Browser Check appear telling him that his IE 11 is out of date?

Comment: You haven't accepted the answer by VekVijay yet. Does that mean that the problem is not solved yet, or that you need other options? If so, there are. Just let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with below steps:

Add website to Compatibility View(You can find in setting)
Try to change(ON/Off) Compatibility View settings in IE11

Comment: I think this is what the problem was. When I added the site to Compatibility View on my computer it did the same as the clients computer. I will have them test it. If it works I will let you know by marking yours as the correct answer. Thanks!